# varchar comparison in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, string, comparison, varchar, string-comparison

I am looking for some  SQL varchar comparison function like  C# string.compare (we can ignore case for now, should return zero when the character expression are same and a non zero expression when they are different)

Basically I have some alphanumeric column in one table which needs to be verified in another table.

I cannot do select A.col1 - B.col1 from (query) as "-" operator cannot be applied on character expressions

I cannot cast my expression as int (and then do a difference/subtraction)  as it fails

```
select cast ('ASXT000R' as int)
Conversion failed when converting varchar 'ASXT000R'  to int
```

`Soundex` would not do it as soundex is same for 2 similar strings

`Difference` would not do it  as `select difference('abc','ABC')` = 4 ([as per msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258844%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx), difference is the difference in the soundex of 2 character expressions and difference =4 implies least different)

I can write a curson to do ascii comparison for each alphanumeric character in each row, but  I was wondering if there  is any other way of doing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we can ignore case for now, should return zero when the character expression are same and a non zero expression when they are different

If that's all you want, you can just use this:

```
CASE WHEN 'a' = 'b' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Note that this expression returns 1 when either of the arguments is NULL. This is probably not what you want. You can use the following to return NULL if either argument is NULL:

```
CASE WHEN 'a' = 'b' THEN 0
     WHEN 'a' <> 'b' THEN 1
END
```

If you want negative and positive values depending on which compares 'larger', you could use this instead:

```
CASE WHEN 'a' < 'b' THEN -1 
     WHEN 'a' = 'b' THEN 0
     WHEN 'a' > 'b' THEN 1
END
```

Comment: How about varchar comparison?

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when a.col1 = b.col1 then 0 else 1 end from a join b on a.id = b.id
```

or

```
select case when lower(a.col1) = lower(b.col1) then 0 else 1 end from a join b on a.id = b.id
```